# Random cron run

Tags: random, cron

I have one php script which I would like to run few times an hour at random time. How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have Cron run the script every minute and put something like this at the start of the PHP script:

```
// stop the script approx. 9 out of 10 times
if( rand( 1, 10 ) != 1 ) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: That's nice, I will try it. And if I would like to run it more often I should change it to like this: if( rand( 1, 10 ) != 1, 2, 3, etc ) {
    die();
} Correct?

Comment: Well that exact syntax won't work, but the idea is right. Perhaps the simplest thing to modify would be something like if( rand( 1, 100 ) > 30 ) { die(); }  which would let the script run 30 % of the time. Change the 30 to change the probability.

Answer (score 0):

Have the cron set to run the script every minute or 5 mins or whatever and place the random timing check in the top of the script itself.